# No response from PHP code using jQuery post()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

I am trying to retrieve data from a PHP file the reads a mySQL db. The data comes in fine on a browser:

http://www.primaryaccess.org/REST/geteasyfile.php?id=25

But when I try to access it using jQuery's get() or post() methods, I get no response. The response header in Firebug says there is the right amount of data, but nothing shows up:

```
$.get("http://www.primaryaccess.org/REST/geteasyfile.php?id=25",function(data) { alert(data); });
```

Here's the PHP:

```
<?
$id=$_GET['id'];
$query="SELECT * FROM easyfile WHERE id = '$id'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
if (($result == false) || (!mysql_numrows($result)))
    echo "Can't load file!";
else    
    echo mysql_result($result,0,"data");
?>
```

Thanks!

Bill

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. [Learn more](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You use a not on a number for num of rows. Please just use if numofrows == 0

Comment: Can you post the response you are getting in Firebug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) and replace `alert()` with `console.log()`. Additionally, your URL looks strange (`'id=25' + id`). I hope you also noticed that there is a [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) in JS, so you need to upload your testfile to the specified domain.

Comment: the getJSON and console didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: You were right, it was a cross-domain issue! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

probably your problem is in the url, you already setted id=25 and then you concatenate the id variable

Hope this help

Comment: Sorry, I hard-coded the 25 for the this message to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a json callback

JS

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.primaryaccess.org/REST/geteasyfile.php?id=25&jsoncallback=?",
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data)
  },
  error: function(error){
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
});
```

PHP

```
<?
$id=$_GET['id'];
$query="SELECT * FROM easyfile WHERE id = '$id'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
if (($result == false) || (!mysql_numrows($result)))
    $result = "Can't load file!";
else    
    $result = mysql_result($result,0,"data");

$result = array('result' => $result);

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($result) . ');'

?>
```